# Highmaps from sharepoint data

Tags: rest, dictionary, highcharts, sharepoint-2010, spservices

I've searched for a few days for examples of now to use high maps with sharepoint data.  We purchased high maps because we are confident there is a way to make the maps from sharepoint data.

The goal would be either to make a map from address or lat long data OR map just on the country of the item.  We are at the phase where we are about to collect data and it's not clear how the data needs to be formatted.  I believe we would either pull the data from the sharepoint list via rest and JSON is SPServices and CAML query,  I've created datatables and a highcgart pie wth test data in the site.

I'm not finding any good samples out there and hoping some experts will weigh in with advice or a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

General rule is that Highcharts runs in any web browser, including web controls or browser widgets in other platforms. If SharePoint has a mechanism of including a web page in some kind of frame, then it should work.

I advice to familiar with the article about preprocessing, http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing and getJSON() functon in jquery.

In the highmaps you can use data points defined as lat/lng.

Further information information about that: 
- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon